# xunit with the moles runner and xml output

Tags: moles, xunit

Has anyone got this working? I'm having trouble using the moles runner with the xunit console and getting the XML output to a file. I'm using the following:

```
moles.runner /x86 /runner:"d:\tools\xunit\xunit.console.clr4.x86.exe" "d:\project\foo.dll" /args:"xml d:\project\foo.xml"
```

moles seems to invoke the runner OK, but I get:

```
error: missing filename for /xml:d:\project\foo.xml
```

Yet, if I put the /d flag on for the moles runner diagnostics it shows the correct runner:

```
d:\tools\xunit\xunit.console.clr4.x86.exe /xml d:\project\foo.xml
```

And if I run that, the tests run (and fail because they are mole tests), but the xml file is created.

Any ideas?